# Write sentence in logic

Tags: logic

> If it rains, he will be at home; otherwise he will go to the market or to
>   school.

Let $p$ be rains, $q$ be at home, $m$ market, $s$ school

Is the correct statement

$p \implies q$? But what about $\neg p \implies m \lor s$?

Which one is correct or used?

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it. You simply need to combine your two statements as follows:
$$
(p \implies q) \wedge (\neg p \implies m \vee s).
$$